# Merge two time series and one data frame to calculate value

Tags: r

I have 2 zoo time series object and a base data frame. I am trying to apply function using these.

```
library("zoo")
```

z1 is as

```
z1 <- structure(c(400L, 125L, 125L, 125L, 120L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), .Dim = c(5L, 3L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("MSFT", "MSFTCALL44", "MSFTPUT44"
)), index = structure(c(15723, 15725, 15726, 15727, 15728), class = "Date"), 
class = "zoo")


           MSFT MSFTCALL44 MSFTPUT44
2013-01-18  400          0         0
2013-01-20  125          0         0
2013-01-21  125          0         0
2013-01-22  125          0         0
2013-01-23  120          0         0
```

z2 is as

```
z2 <- structure(c(0.04, 0.02, 0.03, 0.02, 0.03, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), .Dim = c(5L, 3L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("MSFT", "MSFTCALL44", "MSFTPUT44"
)), index = structure(c(15723, 15725, 15726, 15727, 15728), class = "Date"), 
class = "zoo")


          MSFT MSFTCALL44 MSFTPUT44
2013-01-18 0.04          0         0
2013-01-20 0.02          0         0
2013-01-21 0.03          0         0
2013-01-22 0.02          0         0
2013-01-23 0.03          0         0
```

df is as

```
l <- "Symbol, Underlying, TimeToMaturity, CP, Strike
        MSFTCALL44, MSFT, 0.1, call,44
        MSFTPUT55, MSFT, 0.1, put,44"

i <- read.csv(text = l)

      Symbol Underlying TimeToMaturity    CP Strike
1 MSFTCALL44       MSFT            0.1  call     44
2  MSFTPUT55       MSFT            0.1   put     44
```

I want to apply this formula at every cell

z1[] <- apply(MyFunc(df$CP, df$Underlying, df$Strike, df$maturity, z2[match for symbol]))

**Update**
I believe that using rollapply or apply will do the task, but I am new to R and am unfamiliar with rollapply on two different zoo object and data frame also.

Output:

```
           MSFT         MSFTCALL44                     MSFTPUT44
2013-01-18  400          MyFunc(400,"call",0.04,44)         MyFunc(400,"put",0.04,44)
2013-01-20  125          MyFunc(125,"call",0.02,44)         MyFunc(125,"put",0.02,44)
2013-01-21  125          MyFunc(125,"call",0.03,44)         MyFunc(125,"put",0.03,44)
2013-01-22  125          MyFunc(125,"call",0.02,44)         MyFunc(125,"put",0.02,44)
2013-01-23  120          MyFunc(120,"call",0.03,44)         MyFunc(120,"put",0.03,44)
```

Something like this.

Comment: Based on `df` , what would be the expected output?

Comment: I have updated the question. Output will be in zoo object